# Primes of the form $p=2a^2-1$ satisfying $p^2=2b^2-1$.

Tags: prime-numbers, diophantine-equations, square-numbers

Are there any prime numbers $p$ for which there exist integers $a$ and $b$ such that
$$p=2a^2-1\qquad\text{ and }\qquad p^2=2b^2-1,$$
other than $p=7$?

The fact that $p^2=2b^2-1$ implies that
$$(p+b\sqrt{2})(p-\sqrt{2}b)=-1,$$
and hence that $p+b\sqrt{2}$ is a unit in $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]^{\times}=\langle-1,1+\sqrt{2}\rangle$, from which it quickly follows that 
$$p+b\sqrt{2}=(1+\sqrt{2})^{2n+1},$$
for some integer $n\geq0$. This line of thought shows that $p$ must be of the form
\begin{eqnarray*}
p&=&\frac{(1+\sqrt{2})^{2n+1}+(1-\sqrt{2})^{2n+1}}{2},\\
p&=&\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&6\end{pmatrix}^n\begin{pmatrix}1\\7\end{pmatrix},\\
p&=&a_n\quad\text{ where }\quad a_0=1, a_1=7\quad\text{ and }\quad a_{n+1}=6a_n-a_{n-1},
\end{eqnarray*}
for some integer $n\geq0$.
Checking up to $n=150$ yields no solutions, but unfortunately I'm not computer-savvy enough to check quickly. I am also at a loss how to prove that there are no other such primes. Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: For what it's worth, here's how I would have gone about it: since $$p = (-1 + a \sqrt 2)(1 + a \sqrt 2),$$ then $$p^2 = (-1 + a \sqrt 2)^2 (1 + a \sqrt 2)^2 = 4a^4 - 4a^2 + 1.$$ And then maybe I would have concluded that's a dead end.

Answer (score 4):

Clearly $p\ne 2$ and $p>b>a$. Write $$ p(p-1)= 2(b-a)(a+b)$$

**Case 1:** $$p\mid a+b\implies a+b = kp \implies k<2$$

So $a+b=p$ and $p-1 = 2(b-a)$. From here we get $p=4a-1$ so $$4a-1 = 2a^2-1\implies a=2$$
so $p= 7$.

**Case 2:** $$p\mid b-a\implies p \leq b-a <p $$

Which is impossible.

Comment: Thanks @Servaes

Comment: This is not very polite and it is childis. Are the contributors on this site responsable for acts made by people who runs MSE?

Comment: Also, I spend some time to write the answer down. Did you consider that? You think that is fair. If yes, then you are steping the same way that people who runs MSE does.